# How to search folder of the currently selected file in Open Editors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a file open and actively editing.
If i hit ctrl-f , it will search the current file.
I want to search all files that are in the folder of this currently opened file. Is there a way to do this?

I know i can go to the tree pane, select the parent folder of the file, Shift-Alt-F. the Search window opens and the "files to include"  defaults to the selected folder.
But this is a lot of work to do.
There must be an easier way, or an extension, but ive yet to find anything .

thanks
derek

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an extension I wrote: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).

You could make a keybinding like this (in `keybindings.json`):

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f",          // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "runInSearchPanel",
    "args": {
      // "find": "FIXME",
      "filesToInclude": "${relativeFileDirname}",
      "triggerSearch": true
    }
  }
```

Trigger that keybinding and it will use the parent directory of the currently focused file.  With no `find` value it will use your selected word in the file - or the word at the cursor.

[I am thinking of adding a context menu item for this `Search in Folder` functionality, let me know if that would be of interest.  No keybinding, just a context menu option.]

[image: Find in Folder demo]

Comment: What you show working is perfect and exactly what i want. I installed your extension and added the keybindings. i get the error "command "runInSearchPanel" not found.
im using remove development and the extension gets install on the remove server. maybe that is the issue?

Comment: Update. i tried a local workspace and i see the same issue. it cannot find the command.

Comment: I made a few changes including to the `scope` which might affect your remote issue.  Please download v0.8.8 and see if it makes any difference.  I have never had an issue with a local workspace unless I trigger the command before vscode has installed all the extensions - which can take a little while.

Comment: One of the things I added was an editor or editor tab context menu item to `Search in this Folder` which does the same thing as the keybinding above.  See the Readme for the `runInSearchPanel` command.

Comment: Check that try v0.9.0. And are you running vscode ^v1.56 - that is necessary.

Comment: I had 1.55.2 installed. Updated to 1.57 anf the extension updated to 0.9.0. Seems to be working well now. very useful extension.
Wrt context menu item "Search in Folder". it think this would be  great addition to the extension. Sometimes you want to search just the folder of current file and sometimes the folder and all sub-folder. so i would look at offering both context menus. Thanks for support. derek

Comment: Great - you had me worried there until I remembered the v1.56 requirement.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.  You would like the option to search a folder's files but not any files in subfolders to that folder?